# Pay to many addresses transaction time?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, time, confirmation-time-estimation

I read [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35686/how-do-you-send-to-multiple-addresses-by-paying-a-one-time-fee-which-wallet-sup) about the fees difference when paying to many addresses at once instead of doing it one after another.
I was wondering whether this applies to the transaction time as well.
Is it significantly faster if paying to N addresses at one?
If so, could you please give an example, say N = 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all transactions, "transaction time" is effectively 0. A transaction is created nearly instantaneously and broadcast to the network with no noticeable delay to a human.

What you are confirmed about are confirmation times. The time it takes to get a confirmation is only related to the transaction fee rate paid and the time it takes to mine a block. The size of the transaction is irrelevant.

Comment: Does this mean that given the same fee rate, a transaction to pay one address and another transaction to pay 20 addresses will take same amount of time to be confirmed and appear on blockchain?

Comment: @DarkTemplar By the same fee rate, a transaction with greater weight will pay a higher total fee per individual transaction (but, 1 vs many) and *may* enjoy a benefit when it comes to a miner selecting transactions to include in a proposed block. Many small transactions paying in total a greater fee may not seem as attractive. This, of course, is speculation.

Comment: I think that you mean "What you are concerned about..."

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for clarification. In addition to that, can you give me a "rough" estimate on how longer will it take to transfer 1 to N versus 1 to 1 address.

Comment: There is no such a "roguth estimate" because there is no difference. Even if there were, it would not be noticeable due to the large amount of time in between blocks.