# Multi-destination transaction from paper wallet

Tags: transactions, paper-wallet, private-key-import, sweep

As far as I know, I can make a transaction to a single destination by sweeping/importing private key. How can I make a transaction to multiple destinations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you send to multiple addresses by paying a one time fee? Which wallet supports this?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35686/how-do-you-send-to-multiple-addresses-by-paying-a-one-time-fee-which-wallet-sup)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Bitcoin Core for example. You can find more details in [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35686/how-do-you-send-to-multiple-addresses-by-paying-a-one-time-fee-which-wallet-sup)
answer. You need to import your private key in to Bitcoin Core first.